# Tensorflow tf.squared_difference outputs unexpected shape

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

Newbie here, I am sorry if this question is silly but I couldn't find anything about it online. I am getting an unexpected shape for the output of `tf.squared_difference`. I would expect the obtain of a Tensor with `shape=(100, ?)` shape as the loss from the following snippet

```
[print("Logits",logits,"#Labels",labels,"LOSS",tf.squared_difference(labels,logits)) for logits, labels in zip(logits_series,labels_series)]
```

However it produces `(100,100)` Loss

> Logits Tensor("add_185:0", shape=(100, 1), dtype=float32) #Labels Tensor("unstack_29:0", shape=(100,), dtype=float32) LOSS Tensor("SquaredDifference_94:0", shape=(100, 100), dtype=float32)
>   Logits Tensor("add_186:0", shape=(100, 1), dtype=float32) #Labels Tensor("unstack_29:1", shape=(100,), dtype=float32) LOSS Tensor("SquaredDifference_95:0", shape=(100, 100), dtype=float32)

I have tested another example with following code and gives the expected output shape.

```
myTESTX = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [100, None])
myTESTY = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [100, 1])

print("Test diff X-Y",tf.squared_difference(myTESTX,myTESTY) )
print("Test diff Y-X",tf.squared_difference(myTESTY,myTESTX) )
```

> Test diff X-Y Tensor("SquaredDifference_92:0", shape=(100, ?), dtype=float32)
>   Test diff Y-X Tensor("SquaredDifference_93:0", shape=(100, ?), dtype=float32)

**I am having issue why these two snippets produce different output shape**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a slight difference between your first example (with `logits` and `labels`) and second example (with `myTESTX` and `myTESTY`). `logits` has the same shape as `myTESTY`: `(100, 1)`. However, `labels` has shape `(100,)` (which is NOT a dynamic shape), but `myTESTX` has shape `(100, ?)`.

In the first case (`logits` and `labels`), input shapes are `(100,)` and `(100,1)`, and tensorflow uses broadcasting. Neither input shape is dynamic, so your output shape is static: `(100, 100)` due to broadcasting.

In the second case (`myTESTX` and `myTESTY`), input shapes are `(100, ?)` and `(100, 1)`. The first input shape is dynamic, so your output shape is dynamic: `(100, ?)`.

As a simpler, illustrative example in numpy (which uses the same broadcasting), consider this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10)                # Shape: (10,)
y = np.arange(10).reshape(10,1)  # Shape: (10, 1)
difference = x-y                 # Shape: (10, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't really understand why it is 10,10. The second dimension of the tensors are not 10.

Comment: Right. I agree that it's a confusing/unintuitive example. If it helps, note that shape (10,) is a row vector and shape (10,1) is a column vector. Numpy (and tensorflow) do what's called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). If the shapes of an element-wise operation do not match, numpy tries to copy one of the arrays as many times as it needs to fit the other shape, then it stitches them together.